Why did HaShem allow Christians to proselytize to many nations knowing that they will lead many to idolatry and commit many atrocities?
Why would G-d allow the Christians to bring so much misinformation and so much tragedies to many people throughout the world? This is not to say that Christianity hasn't made a number of positive contributions to the world of course but wouldn't it be more ideal if G-d were to have propagated another group that was not as antisemitic and hostile and more monotheistic than the Christians?

I once heard that Gd allowed the Christians to become numerous because they popularized in the world the idea of a messiah, and Gd allowed the Muslims to become numerous because they popularized the idea of one Gd

Yes, I believe this is written by Rambam

Why do you ask this question instead of "why did not Hashem allow Jewish people to become numerous?"

@Y DJ Because Jews don't proselytize and Christians do

@Y DJ
כֶּן־הוּא, אִלּוּ הָיָה רֻבֵּנוּ מְקַבֵּל הַדַּלּוּת כְּנִיעָה לֵאלֹהִים וּבַעֲבוּר תּוֹרָתוֹ, לֹא הָיָה מַנִּיחֵנוּ הָעִנְיָן הָאֱלֹהִי כָּל הַזְּמָן הָאָרֹךְ הַזֶּה.

I always struggle with the "wouldn't it have been more ideal if God..." questions. Wouldn't it have been more ideal if He had never hid and made a yeitzer hara? Everything else after that is just stamp collecting

Christians reduced the amount of idolatry in the world and enhanced Torah values

@ClintEastwood Christians did make the concept of monotheism, albeit their twisted concept of it, widespread throughout the world but the claim of them enhancing Torah values remains to be seen

@RabbiKaii I'll do you one better, wouldn't it be better had G-d not put the Tree of Knowledge and the serpent in Gan Eden?

@ddas91600 Exactly. There's a much more fundamental principle that exists that will rule out this question. You can find it in the Zohar - the yeitzer hara is something Hashem needs as part of His plan.

@ddas91600 I mean... the Judeo-Christian values are objectively better and more humane than those found in certain middle eastern countries under the strict control of a certain other religion. Wouldn't you agree?

There’s also the Gemara about when Chazal trapped the yetzer hara and the chickens stopped laying eggs

You should read the bible itself and pre-Rabbinic sources to better know the reason behind Christianity. Jacob Neusner has a great book on "Evil and Suffering", its preview is on google books; also read his books on first century Judaism. Also on Jews who accept Trinity https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/502059?lang=bi

@Michael16 so, where in the Hebrew Bible explains why G-d allowed Christians to take over most of the world? Which pre-rabbinic sources are you referring to?

This is a profound question that touches on the larger issue of why G-d allows things that may seem contrary to the ideal world we envision. One perspective, as mentioned by Rambam, is that Christianity and Islam have both contributed to spreading the concept of monotheism across the world, even if the way they do so is not entirely in line with Jewish thought. These religions, while problematic in certain aspects, have played a role in bringing many people closer to understanding some form of G-d, albeit in ways that are different from Judaism.
It's also important to consider the role of free will. G-d allows people, and even entire groups, the freedom to choose their paths, even if that includes spreading beliefs or committing actions that lead to suffering. This idea can be linked to the broader question of why G-d permits any form of evil or hardship in the world—humans are granted free will, and unfortunately, that often leads to misuse of that freedom.
Moreover, we can look at the long arc of history. While Christianity may have led to suffering for the Jewish people at various points in history, it has also introduced moral and ethical teachings that, in many ways, align with Torah values. The existence of such a complex relationship between these religions and the Jewish people may point to a larger divine plan, where even actions or movements that seem harmful can eventually lead to greater awareness of G-d and His will in the world.
Ultimately, while we may struggle with understanding why certain things happen or why G-d allows them, we trust that there is a purpose, even in events that seem painful or confusing from our perspective.

Welcome to MiYodeya Robbie. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

I'm almost certain this has been asked and answered here before, but we'll do it once again. Maimonides, Laws of Kings and Their Wars, 11:7--8. You can read Maimonides' language there.
But in short, Christianity and Islam have both spread the vocabulary of monotheism throughout the world; even if in ways that Judaism would consider problematic.

And the vocabulary of Messiah

This question is basically the same as the more common "Why does G allow bad things to happen?"
This is more complex then saying that one religion proselytizes and the other does not.
Fundamentally G created us with Free will, we are all able to choose to follow G or not. This goes both ways, G will not interfere with our ability to make choices, if a person rejects G then that is their choice.
I understand that the topic of free will is not as easily reconciled within the Jewish faith. And I've seen arguments for determinism as well as for free will. I believe it is called "Bechirah chofshit" which I think was supposed to be based on the 2nd book of Moses.

I (G) have set before you life and death, blessing and curse: therefore choose life (2nd Book of Moses "Deuteronomy" 30:19)

This is true on higher levels as well, a group of people will be "permitted" to do as they please. To choose life or death.
As for the suffering they cause, it is permitted because it is a byproduct of sin. G does not want us to break his commandments and all preventable suffering is because we have turned away from HaShem.

On a side note: I think any Christian denomination that is anti-semitic is not Christian at all by their own definitions, Christians should respect jews naturally due to the shared connection to G.
Edit: I'm an Eastern Orthodox Christian, as far as I know Christians are supposed to respect the root, we are to love even those who persecute us, and so on. I'm sorry for those ... others who make you feel otherwise. I cannot judge them, but I trust that G would.

I think any Christian denomination that is anti-semitic is not Christian at all by their own definitions, Christians should respect jews naturally due to the shared connection to G. That conclusion does not fit with a clear reading of the New Testament.

@RabbiKaii To what are you referring to precisely?

@Wyrsa you do realize many Christians hold jews culpable of deicide, and that the Pharisees (orthodox rabbis) were Jesus' nemesis and were often portrayed negatively in the NT...that's only 2 out of many reasons why many Christians oppose Jews

@ddas91600 Romans 11:18 do not be arrogant toward the branches; but if you are arrogant, remember that it is not you who supports the root, but the root supports you. I cannot relate those schismatic churches that would say jews are guilty of deicide. Regarding the issue of negative portrayal... I mean just look in the OT and you'll see countless examples of the nation of israel being portrayed negatively. The first one that comes to mind is that they couldn't even wait for Moses to come back down the mountain after witnessing multiple miracles from HaShem.

@Wyrsa John 8:44 shows that Jesus believed not all Jews are G-d's people, and that some are of the devil. That doesn't help things. Jews weren't really depicted negatively in the OT, it was just objectively accounting how they acted, what they were doing. The depiction of the Pharisees in the NT was purely villainous in nature, as though they were always wrong and immoral compared to Jesus who was always right and can do no wrong. Plus there are many Christians who denounce the OT, think that it's all wrong, and that the NT is the correction and improvement of the OT.

@ddas91600 Yes, some jews were awful people. Some atheists are. Some christian pastors are criminals. Some jews are criminals. Some atheists are as well. Oh dear. That is not a judgement against the totality of a nation or a religion, and it never should be used as such. Likewise we shouldn't view either side as a black and white. Most of the issues presented are about the Spirit of the Law being not upheld. Care more to be "seen" obeying the law, then actually fulfilling it. The comments are not a place for debate... we can politely converse in a chat if you so desire.

@Wyrsa forgive me if I gave you the impression I was generalizing, you're right, there are bad people in every group, I respect that you are not prejudiced towards Jews and Judaism, but all I intended to do was show you that Christianity and Judaism do not exactly gel together, despite good intentions

@ddas91600 Fair enough, though I feel like you could have been more diplomatic about it. Same goes for Kaii. If you start the conversation with heavy distrust or light loathing... it will be very rare for anyone to want to listen to you. Outside of this echo chamber of similar thought. I came here to answer a question, and condemned those "christians" who were anti-semitic. If I wanted to stir up trouble, I wouldn't have respected how you don't say "G_d" or similar things. Peace be with you, and I hope kaii will be less ... pointy the next time someone nice looks in your SE.

@Wyrsa pointy? Is that a freudian slip?

@RabbiKaii I again reject the concept that any entire faith or nation is responsible for the actions of some of members. That is what you accuse christians of doing to your faith. Your first comment here was as you described it (before your comment was edited), sadly others are not on this subject. I am sad on your behalf that Christians have hurt you so. I cannot fix that, I appreciate that you rewrote your comment. In my family, we call someone "pointy" when they are unkind or in a bad mood. I honestly didn't even think of any stereotype at all. My apologies.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RabbiKaii deleted that comment, you are right. That was the other person. It got confusing quickly. Peace be with you.

@Wyrsa friend, since you chose to enrol yourself in a Jewish forum, it is only appropriate that you anticipate hearing the Jewish perspective, the same way a Jew would anticipate hearing the Christian perspective if he were to come to an Orthodox Christian forum. Furthermore, there is a great deal of debating amongst our sages/theologians, great deal of differences in perspective. Lots of questioning the texts, too, as you can see. Judaism is the total opposite of an echo chamber.

@ddas91600 you should see the christianity SE... we have objectively "heretics" from each of our points of view, that must be respected. The Jehovas witness or Mormons... and then catholics, protestants, orthodox... I have total appreciation for the view of christianity as a heresy. I suppose even SE is not immune to intellectual weakness. Anyways, I only truly came here to answer the question above. Gd gives us free will, we are responsible for our own actions, the basis for that is within the torah/old testament. So I felt even as a christian I could provide an answer. Peace be with you.

You bring two points against Christianity. First: antisemitism. While it is unfortunate that historically there has been a strong antisemitic streak amongst various Christian groups and individual theologians, personally (as a Christian), it makes zero sense to me why a Christian would be antisemitic. The scriptures certainly don't teach such a thing. Jesus and all the early Christians were Jews, the NT asserts that salvation is of the Jews, that non-Jewish Christians have been grafted onto Israel, etc.
Some might cite that Christ was put to death by Jews - but even that doesn't make sense. In the first case because Jesus came to die - that was his intention. He even says that no one takes his life - but he lays it down of his own freewill (John 10:18). In the second case, not all Jews persecuted Christ - many followed him. But even those that did persecute him, he prayed that they be forgiven (Luke 23:34). How can a Christian then turn around and punish these individuals for it - let alone all the Jews who didn't persecute him then, or all the Jews since that time who played no part in it? It's both illogical and irreverent. Not to mention that any hate is completely contradictory to Christ's teachings.
The second issue you bring up is the issue of monotheism. Whilst there are some notable individual exceptions (Justin Martyr), Christianity on the whole has always been monotheistic. The Trinity doctrine arose out of a struggle to maintain this monotheism in combination with some bad interpretations of scripture. Namely: there are a couple passages that refer to Christ as God in some sense. I myself am not a Trinitarian and could spend a long time going over the errors of it with you.
It seems to me that, due to an early break between Christianity and Judaism, the early theologians were more informed by Greek Philosophy (especially Platonism) than by Judaism and the Tanakh. If they had studied the Tanakh closer then they would know that both angels and men have been called God and spoken in the first person as if God himself. In particularly, God declared that he would make Moses Elohim to Pharaoh, and in Deuteronomy 29:6 Moses even speaks in the first person as if God. With such biblical precedence in mind, it makes far more sense to interpret those coupe passages that refer to the Son as God in the same manner as we would these passages for Moses than to try to assert that the Son is literally God Almighty himself.
I won't bore you with my long list of complaints about the Trinity and the councils started by Constantine, but suffice it to say I agree that the Trinity doctrine is problematic. However, I don't find it problematic for not being monotheistic enough so much as it is an example of what happens when you design theology through committee. It's an illogical mess that everyone was forced to swallow through threats of exile and death - and even though it wasn't finalized until hundreds of years after Christ, it is somehow treated as "the defining belief" of Christianity. It's quite ridiculous.
Nevertheless, being a Christian does not require the Trinity in the least; and I am proof of that. Whilst the Trinity has historically been the enforced position of the various churches, there have always been plenty who opposed it. Those people just have a way of being put to death - like how John Calvin burned Michael Servetus back during the reformation. Isaac Newton kept his Christology private for the same reason - avoiding persecution.
Now, it is only fair to point out that the Hebrews themselves were even worse on the points of monotheism & idolatry. As the scriptures record, they would often fall into idolatry and start worshiping the gods of the surrounding nations, like Baal. According to some scholars, the Canaanite goddess Asherah was even worshiped as the wife of the LORD. This would have been straight up polytheism. And, of course, let's not forget that the very first High Priest of Israel constructed a Golden Calf for the people to worship right after God delivered them from Egypt!
So it seems to me that the underlying issue is less why has God chosen to act through Christianity despite the evils that some have done and some of the bad mainstream theology than it is: why has God chosen to act through man?
Let's be honest: no matter what group of people God chooses to act through, they will be sinners. The group will contain some really good individuals who devote themselves to God (like Moses), and there will be a lot of corrupt individuals making a mockery of things (like the generation of Israel killed off in the wilderness before entering the Promised Land). And even the paragons of excellence will fall short - like how Moses sinned against God and was denied entry into the Promised Land.
